# Tip Calculator (addEventListener)

Tags: javascript, html, math

I'm trying to create a simple form with a tip calculator. I can't get the "addEventListener" to work. I am confused as to how to add the tip and bill variables into the code. All my files are linked correctly. Here is my code:

```js
    function calc() {
        var bill = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
        var tip = bill * .20;
        var total_bill = bill + tip;

        document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= "$"+Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);    

    });
      }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
        </header>
        <form action="javascript:void(calc())">
            Amount: $<input id="bill" type="text">
            <br>
            <button id="myBtn">Find Tip</button>
    
            <p id="demo"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: why do you need to addEventListener? clicking the button already calls your function (sumbit of the form), just manipulate the "demo" innerHTML directly...

Comment: The problem is that the calc function is called in response to a form submission attempt. It's not until then that the handler for the button is attached. So, you'd have to click the button twice to get it to work. However, you're also missing the `}` that closes the `calc` function. Add another bracket, then click the button twice and voila!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need addEventListener. Try this it works just fine. Hope it helps :)

```js
function calc() {
    var bill = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
    var tip = bill * .20;
    var total_bill = bill + tip;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= "$"+Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);    
};
```

```html
<form>
  Amount: $<input id="bill" type="text">
  <button type="button" id="myBtn">Find Tip</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `onclick` event instead of `addEventListener`

```js
    document.getElementById('myBtn').onclick = function(){
      var bill = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
      var tip = bill * .20;
      var total_bill = bill + tip;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= "$"+Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);  
    }
```

```html
    <form>
        Amount: $<input id="bill" type="text">
        <button type="button" id="myBtn">Find Tip</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </form>
```

OR

```js
    function ID(ID){
      return document.getElementById(ID);
    }

    ID('myBtn').onclick = function(){
      var bill = Number(ID('bill').value);
      var tip = bill * .20;
      var total_bill = bill + tip;
      ID("demo").innerHTML= "$"+Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);  
    }
```

```html
        <form>
            Amount: $<input id="bill" type="text">
            <button type="button" id="myBtn">Find Tip</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet, without using `addEventListener`

```js
function calc() {
    var bill = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
    var tip = bill * .20;
    var total_bill = bill + tip;
    //removed addEventListener, as here it is not need
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "$" + Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);
} //added
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
  </header>
  <!-- changes: removed `action`, added onsubmit -->
  <form onsubmit="calc();return false">
    Amount: $
    <input id="bill" type="text">
    <br>
    <button id="myBtn">Find Tip</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

This one uses `addEventListener`:

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var bill = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
  var tip = bill * .20;
  var total_bill = bill + tip;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "$" + Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
  </header>
  <!-- changes: removed `action`-->
  <form>
    Amount: $
    <input id="bill" type="text">
    <br>
    <button id="myBtn">Find Tip</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```